# Node.js/Express req.body of POST is empty. POST request sent through Postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Currently my code is this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require('../helpers/db');

var data = {
    "1": 127,
    "2": 236,
    "3": 348
}

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send(data);
});

router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    var key = req.params.id;
    res.send({ [key]: data[key] });
});

router.post('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log(id);
})
```

My goal is to be able to POST a value from Postman to API/values/:id, save that value under the id key and then save that "key": value pair in the data variable. Unfortunately, when I try to POST anything and then access it with req.body, I get {} or undefined.

app.js

```
var routes = require('./routes/');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressSession = require('express-session');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession({
                  secret: 'secretText',
                  saveUninitialized: true,
                  resave: true
                }))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes.home);
app.use('/values', routes.values);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: To access body of `req` object you need `body-parser` middleware available in same module

Comment: What settings are you using with Postman?

Comment: I post form-data key-value pair to http://myipadress/values/1. I haven't touched any postman settings.

Answer (score 3):

To do so you need to have body-parser plugin of expressjs.

Install it using `npm install --save body-parser` and then use it like below

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

express()
  .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  }))
  .use(bodyParser.json())
```

Comment: I have done that in my app.js file. Isn't there where it's supposed to be?

Comment: I face same problem I and I was added body-parser too. but finally, I made an html page with form and send post request from there.

Comment: The whole point is that it shouldn't be from a html page form.

Comment: Hi @Bobimaru , it should be in app.js can you double check everything is same as above. Also the expressjs version is comaptible with the bodyparser version you are using

Comment: Everything seems up to date.

Comment: Can you post the appjs